# Speed of NSFileManager CopyFileAtPath is wildly different than finder in cases

Tags: macos, performance, copy, nsfilemanager

I am using NSFileManager to copy a lot of files from one drive to another.

In some cases I am seeing users say " The app is unusable, It transfers at 0.33 MB/s, on a USB2 Connection. What would take me 10 min when I just Drag and drop"

I am running this on a background thread - is that maybe the issue?

```
secondaryTask=dispatch_queue_create(      "com.myorg.myapp.task2",NULL);
dispatch_sync(secondaryTask,^{

    NSFileManager *manager;
    [manager copyItemAtPath:sourceFile toPath:filePath error:&error];

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to OS X actually throttling my app. Some users actually see this in the log:

> 5/9/16 15:26:31.000 kernel[0]: process MyApp[937] thread 36146 caught burning CPU! It used more than 50% CPU (Actual recent usage: 91%) over 180 seconds. thread lifetime cpu usage 90.726617 seconds, (49.587139 user, 41.139478 system) ledger info: balance: 90006865992 credit: 90006865992 debit: 0 limit: 90000000000 (50%) period: 180000000000 time since last refill (ns): 98013987431

So... this is a GCD question... and Ive brought it up with Apple directly.

Comment: Did you hear anything back?

Comment: Nothing useful.